# Adding an external WMS service using REST service with Geoserver

Tags: wms, php, geoserver-rest-api

I'm trying to add an External WMS layer to geoserver with a PHP page, using the REST service of Geoserver. I've already read the tutorials for creating the geoserver features (http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/restconfig/rest-config-api.html), but i couldn't find the way to create a new store and layer with an external WMS service.

in other words: I have the URL of the external WMS service (=store), the layer i want to publish (=layer) and the epgs i want to use.

Is there a way to load all of these information in the geoserver schema?

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately this is not documented in the api reference or samples. But here is the gist of it.

First create the store:

```
POST /rest/workspaces/<ws>/wmsstores

<wmsStore>
   <name>wms</name>
   <capabilitiesURL>http://somehost/wms?</capabilitiesURL>
   <workspace>sf</workspace>
</wmsStore>
```

And then create the layers:

```
POST /rest/workspaces/<ws>/wmsstores/wms/wmslayers/

<wmsLayer>
   <name>layerName</name>
</wmsLayer>
```

Comment: Thank you jdeolive for the answer, i'll try to implement this code in my php application. But, i can't figure out how could do that. Can you tell me with more details how can i add this POST code to a php page? Maybe this is a stupid question, but really, i can't figure how to use this REST commands with php

Comment: You can add <type>WMS</type> into wmsStore-tag so in the datasources overview in geoserver the type of this datasource gets specified instead of default "?" (applies for geoserver 2.2.3 in my case).

I also had to specify header "Content-Type=application/xml".

Comment: If you need a complete guide, go here http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/200813/using-geotools-or-geoservermanager-to-add-a-layer-using-just-an-url

Answer (score 0):

You can also manually configure GeoServer for external WMS layers as explained [here](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/data/wms.html).